# if inside for conditoin keeps giving me worng feed back

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, hashmap

I am tring to go through a hashmap and extract each ArrayList inside it and match the sexith index with the value "thelessonyouneed"

```
String thelessonyouneed = "Math";
for (int che = 0 ;  che < dataofqusations.size(); che++) {
    ArrayList<String> datatobe = (ArrayList<String>) dataofqusations.get(String.valueOf(che));
    if (thelessonyouneed == datatobe.get(6)) {
        System.out.println(che);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
};
```

the out put gives me wrong info

```
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: No match
I/System.out: Match
```

The correct info should be all indexes except 2. What is the thing I am missing here !?

Comment: you need to use `thelessonyouneed.equals( datatobe.get(6))` o compare strings